# Visual Studio 2017 UnitTest not running

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unit-testing

I am learning C# so I apologise if I cannot be extremely precise in describing the error.

I was following Pluralsight course and at the section of Unit Testing I realised that the Unit Test does not run on my projects.

It casts the following error:

```
[19/11/2018 22:13:26 Error] Failed to launch testhost with error: System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> Microsoft.Build.Exceptions.InvalidProjectFileException: The project file could not be loaded. Could not find file 'C:\Users\Daniele\source\repos\DateTime\UnitTestProject1\bin\x86\Debug\UnitTestProject1.build.appxrecipe'.  C:\Users\Daniele\source\repos\DateTime\UnitTestProject1\bin\x86\Debug\UnitTestProject1.build.appxrecipe ---> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not find file 'C:\Users\Daniele\source\repos\DateTime\UnitTestProject1\bin\x86\Debug\UnitTestProject1.build.appxrecipe'.
   at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
   at System.IO.FileStream.Init(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, Int32 rights, Boolean useRights, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES secAttrs, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy, Boolean useLongPath, Boolean checkHost)
   at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share)
   at Microsoft.Build.Internal.XmlReaderExtension..ctor(String file)
   at Microsoft.Build.Construction.ProjectRootElement.LoadDocument(String fullPath, Boolean preserveFormatting)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Microsoft.Build.Shared.ProjectFileErrorUtilities.VerifyThrowInvalidProjectFile(Boolean condition, String errorSubCategoryResourceName, BuildEventFileInfo projectFile, Exception innerException, String resourceName, Object[] args)
   at Microsoft.Build.Construction.ProjectRootElement.LoadDocument(String fullPath, Boolean preserveFormatting)
   at Microsoft.Build.Construction.ProjectRootElement..ctor(String path, ProjectRootElementCache projectRootElementCache, Boolean preserveFormatting)
   at Microsoft.Build.Construction.ProjectRootElement.CreateProjectFromPath(String projectFile, ProjectRootElementCache projectRootElementCache, Boolean preserveFormatting)
   at Microsoft.Build.Construction.ProjectRootElement.<>c.<OpenProjectOrSolution>b__201_0(String path, ProjectRootElementCache cache)
   at Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.ProjectRootElementCache.Get(String projectFile, OpenProjectRootElement openProjectRootElement, Boolean isExplicitlyLoaded, Nullable`1 preserveFormatting)
   at Microsoft.Build.Construction.ProjectRootElement.OpenProjectOrSolution(String fullPath, IDictionary`2 globalProperties, String toolsVersion, ProjectRootElementCache projectRootElementCache, Boolean isExplicitlyLoaded)
   at Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.ProjectCollection.LoadProject(String fileName, IDictionary`2 globalProperties, String toolsVersion)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.UwpTestHostRuntimeProvider.RecipeFile.get_Project()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.UwpTestHostRuntimeProvider.RecipeFile.get_Architecture()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.UwpTestHostRuntimeProvider.Deployer.Microsoft.VisualStudio.UwpTestHostRuntimeProvider.IDeployer.get_DeploymentArchitecture()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.UwpTestHostRuntimeProvider.UwpTestHostManager.<LaunchHostAsync>d__35.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.UwpTestHostRuntimeProvider.UwpTestHostManager.<Microsoft-VisualStudio-TestPlatform-ObjectModel-Host-ITestRuntimeProvider-LaunchTestHostAsync>d__30.MoveNext()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ThrowIfExceptional(Boolean includeTaskCanceledExceptions)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.GetResultCore(Boolean waitCompletionNotification)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.get_Result()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.CrossPlatEngine.Client.ProxyOperationManager.SetupChannel(IEnumerable`1 sources)
---> (Inner Exception #0) Microsoft.Build.Exceptions.InvalidProjectFileException: The project file could not be loaded. Could not find file 'C:\Users\Daniele\source\repos\DateTime\UnitTestProject1\bin\x86\Debug\UnitTestProject1.build.appxrecipe'.  C:\Users\Daniele\source\repos\DateTime\UnitTestProject1\bin\x86\Debug\UnitTestProject1.build.appxrecipe ---> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not find file 'C:\Users\Daniele\source\repos\DateTime\UnitTestProject1\bin\x86\Debug\UnitTestProject1.build.appxrecipe'.
   at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
   at System.IO.FileStream.Init(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, Int32 rights, Boolean useRights, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES secAttrs, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy, Boolean useLongPath, Boolean checkHost)
   at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share)
   at Microsoft.Build.Internal.XmlReaderExtension..ctor(String file)
   at Microsoft.Build.Construction.ProjectRootElement.LoadDocument(String fullPath, Boolean preserveFormatting)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Microsoft.Build.Shared.ProjectFileErrorUtilities.VerifyThrowInvalidProjectFile(Boolean condition, String errorSubCategoryResourceName, BuildEventFileInfo projectFile, Exception innerException, String resourceName, Object[] args)
   at Microsoft.Build.Construction.ProjectRootElement.LoadDocument(String fullPath, Boolean preserveFormatting)
   at Microsoft.Build.Construction.ProjectRootElement..ctor(String path, ProjectRootElementCache projectRootElementCache, Boolean preserveFormatting)
   at Microsoft.Build.Construction.ProjectRootElement.CreateProjectFromPath(String projectFile, ProjectRootElementCache projectRootElementCache, Boolean preserveFormatting)
   at Microsoft.Build.Construction.ProjectRootElement.<>c.<OpenProjectOrSolution>b__201_0(String path, ProjectRootElementCache cache)
   at Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.ProjectRootElementCache.Get(String projectFile, OpenProjectRootElement openProjectRootElement, Boolean isExplicitlyLoaded, Nullable`1 preserveFormatting)
   at Microsoft.Build.Construction.ProjectRootElement.OpenProjectOrSolution(String fullPath, IDictionary`2 globalProperties, String toolsVersion, ProjectRootElementCache projectRootElementCache, Boolean isExplicitlyLoaded)
   at Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.ProjectCollection.LoadProject(String fileName, IDictionary`2 globalProperties, String toolsVersion)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.UwpTestHostRuntimeProvider.RecipeFile.get_Project()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.UwpTestHostRuntimeProvider.RecipeFile.get_Architecture()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.UwpTestHostRuntimeProvider.Deployer.Microsoft.VisualStudio.UwpTestHostRuntimeProvider.IDeployer.get_DeploymentArchitecture()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.UwpTestHostRuntimeProvider.UwpTestHostManager.<LaunchHostAsync>d__35.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.UwpTestHostRuntimeProvider.UwpTestHostManager.<Microsoft-VisualStudio-TestPlatform-ObjectModel-Host-ITestRuntimeProvider-LaunchTestHostAsync>d__30.MoveNext()<---

[19/11/2018 22:13:26 Informational] ========== Run test finished: 0 run (0:00:00.0535907) ==========
```

I have found different resources online
https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/212059/unable-to-debug-unit-test-visual-studio-enterprise.html

And different solutions:
first to disable a VPN (which I don't have) and then to Run `“set-mppreference -EnableNetworkProtection 0”` in an elevated PowerShell prompt, and restart VS.

None of this method has ultimately work and I am unable to run any test.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is the appxrecipe is not in the bin folder of your unit test project.

You can create the appxrecipe file by creating an app package for the unit test project.  To create the app package right click your unit test project > "Store" > "Create App Packages".

Once that is complete the appxrecipe file should be in the bin folder of your project and visual studio should be able to run your unit tests.